# Ajax call fails in IE with requests from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm making a trivial ajax CORS request from HTTPS to HTTP, and it's working fine on every browser, except IE. It's not even trying to make a request and fails immediately. There is no error messages in console.

This fails even without trying (there is no network traffic), then executed from secure site:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://foo.bar'
}).done(function() {
    alert('success');
}).fail(function() {
    alert('fail');
});
```

I'm using IE 10 in Standards Mode. Is there any way to make it work with HTTP? It's obvious it blocks unsecure request from secure site, but maybe it's possible to change this using browser settings?

Comment: What do the responseText and errorStatus property say? Also check the network traffic, you can do this with F12 and then Network.

Comment: @Knerd it fails without issuing request. So there is no network traffic.

Comment: Which IE version? Which jquery version? And are there errors in the console?

Comment: Try `$.support.cord=true;`

Comment: @sb9 it's IE10 in Standards mode. No, there is no errors in console.

Comment: @AmitAgrawal it's `$.support.cors` actually, but anyway that doesn't helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly there seems to be no solution for this.

Your best alternative option (for quick solution) is to implement HTTPS (directly or as a proxy for external HTTP-only service) using self-signed certificate and add it to exception list.